# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un menú accesible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accesibilidad

Tengo el siguiente menú (simplificado):

```css
nav ul, nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav > ul {
  background:#ccc;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
}

nav > ul > li {
  line-height:40px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding:0 10px;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:40px;
  background:#aaa;
  display:none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  width:150px;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sección 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sección 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sección 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 3.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sección 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Ese menú funciona, si paso el ratón sobre las secciones 2 y 3, se abre un submenú en el que se pueden elegir más opciones, pero tiene un problema: si el usuario sólo utiliza el teclado (porque no tenga ratón o porque esté usando un lector de pantalla), los submenús no se abren correctamente.

Por ejemplo, si le damos al botón tabulador va saltando a "Sección 1", luego "Sección 2" (y no se abre su submenú), luego a "Sección 3" (en lugar de entrar en el submenú de "Sección 2", y tampoco se abre su submenú) y por último "Sección 4".

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando llegue a la "Sección 2" o "Sección 3" se abran los submenús? ¿Sería posible usar los cursores y no sólo el tabulador? ¿Es posible realizarlo sólo con HTML+CSS o haría falta JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando el plugin de [Adobe - Accessible-Mega-Menu](http://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/) y creando un pequeño script que abre el submenu cuando ese detecta si esta en `focus`.

```js
$(function () {
   
   // inicializar accessibleMegaMenu
   $('nav').accessibleMegaMenu();
            
  // Hack para que el megamenu no muestre flash de animación css después de cargar la página.
  setTimeout(function(){ $('body').removeClass('init'); }, 500);  
  
  // Abre el menu cuando detecta si esta en focus con TAB
  $(window).on('keyup', function (e) {
    
    var codeTab = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    
    if (codeTab == 9 && $('#focus_1:focus').length) {
      
      $('a#focus_1').trigger('mouseenter');
    }

    if (codeTab == 9 && $('#focus_2:focus').length) {
      
      $('a#focus_2').trigger('mouseenter');
    }
    
   }); 
});
```

```css
.nav-menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 15;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-item > a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

navigation item 
.nav-item > a:focus,
.nav-item > a.open {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

navigation item
.nav-item > a.open {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sub-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 2.6em;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sub-nav.open {
  display: block;
}

.sub-nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sub-nav li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-menu">        
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#">Sección 1</a>
    </li>        
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="focus_1" href="#">Sección 2</a>    
      <div class="sub-nav">
        <ul class="sub-nav-group">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>        
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a id="focus_2" href="#">Sección 3</a>       
      <div class="sub-nav">
        <ul class="sub-nav-group">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 3.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>        
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#">Sección 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://terrillthompson.com/tests/menus/accessible-mega-menu/js/jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js"></script>
```

Comment: En algunos casos, no se abren los submenús cuando uso el tabulador

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro -  Se abre solo en la primera vez... estoy mirando otra opción... pero creo que sin javascript no se podrá

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - Mira esta demo: [demo](http://jsbin.com/dubuyob/edit?html,css,js,output)... he usado el plugin de [Accessible Mega Menu](http://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/)... puedes moverte con las flechas del teclado... mira si te sirve sino borrare esta respuesta

Comment: JavaScript es una opción

Comment: La demo que enlazas se ve bien, lo único es que no se abre el menú a no ser que pulses hacia abajo, ¿sabes si se puede configurar para que se abra tan pronto como la opción "padre" esté activa?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - Creo que lo tengo listo... tal como lo quieres

Comment: Esta respuesta funciona como esperaba. Recibo un error raro en JavaScript cuando uso el Alt+Tab para ir hacia atrás, pero funciona, que es lo que importa. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el atributo [`tabindex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) para hacer los elementos `li` focuseables. Después, mediante el selector [`focus`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act), hacer que tus submenús se muestren mediante `display:block`.

De esta manera tu podrás navegar mediante el tabulador por los distintos elementos del menú y se mostrarán los correspondientes submenús.

Te dejo tu código modificado:

```css
nav ul, nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav > ul {
  background:#ccc;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
}

nav > ul > li {
  line-height:40px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding:0 10px;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:40px;
  background:#aaa;
  display:none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  width:150px;
  padding:0 10px;
}

li:focus ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sección 1</a></li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <a href="#">Sección 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0">
      <a href="#">Sección 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sección 3.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sección 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: El problema de este código es que no puedes seleccionar ninguno de los submenús, sólo verlos.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Sí, es verdad, no se puede acceder a los submenus. Sin embargo, el OP sólo habla de mostrarlos (_¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando llegue a la "Sección 2" o "Sección 3" se abran los submenús?_). Estaba esperando algún tipo de contestación por parte del OP para estar completamente seguro. De todas maneras, esta noche me pondré a intentar sacar una solución para que también pueda acceder a los submenus.

Comment: La respuesta de @aldanux sí que funciona así que supongo que en breve la marcará como respondida. Revísala y si puedes mejorarla sin librerías pues mejor.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Esta noche me pondré a ello ^^

Comment: Esta era mi primera respuesta... antes de [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/33260/1)... pero parece ser imposible de hacerlo sin javascript